# AutoMapper on .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-3.1

In a Net Core 3.1 application i' m trying to use the AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 7.
In solution i have 3 projects:

- Content (start project)
- Core
- Entity framework

After nuget installation, this is my code:

Startup.cs in Content Project:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Project.Content.EntityFrameWork;
using Project.Content.Dto;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Project.Content
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            // Auto Mapper Configurations
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapping));

            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionString:Default"];
            services.AddDbContext<ProjectContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

AutoMapping.cs in Content project:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Project.Content.Core.Domain.Model;

namespace Project.Content.Dto
{
    class AutoMapping : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapping()
        {
            CreateMap<Exercise, ExerciseDto>();
            CreateMap<ExerciseDto, Exercise>();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Controller where I'm trying to map:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Project.Content.EntityFrameWork;
using Project.Content.Dto;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project.Content.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/exercise")]
    public class ExercisesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ExercisesController> _logger;
        private ProjectContext _dbContext;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public ExercisesController(ILogger<ExercisesController> logger, ProjectContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ExerciseDto GetById(int id)
        {

            var exercise =  _mapper.Map<ExerciseDto>(_dbContext.Exercises.Where(x => x.Id == id));
            return exercise;
        }
    }
}
```

In this controller when it tries to map objects it shows the error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: EntityQueryable`1 -> ExerciseDto
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[[Project.Content.Core.Domain.Model.Exercise,
>   Project.Content.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] -> Project.Content.Dto.ExerciseDto    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , EntityQueryable`1 , ExerciseDto ,
>   ResolutionContext )    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ,
>   ResolutionContext )    at
>   Project.Content.Controllers.ExercisesController.GetById(Int32 id) in
>   C:\Projects\Project\Project.Content\Project.Content.Service\Controllers\ExercisesController.cs:line
>   44    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
>   endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to map the `IQueryable<T>`, because it uses [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution). You need to execute the query by using something like `ToList()` or `ToListAsync()` before you attempt to map it.

You are also trying to map a collection to a single item. You should instead map to a collection. The end result looks something like this

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ExerciseDto GetById(int id)
{
  var exercises =  _dbContext.Exercises.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();
  return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ExerciseDto>>(exercises);
}
```

Alternatively, you could leverage AutoMappers [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) to perform a projection, which could result in better SQL performance as it will attempt to only query the necessary data. This may look something like so

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ExerciseDto GetById(int id)
{
  return _mapper.ProjectTo<ExerciseDto>(_dbContext.Exercises.Where(x => x.Id == id)).ToList();
}
```

As a side note, if you intend for this query to be a single object, or not found if it doesn't exist, you might use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`. Also, you can return an IActionResult to leverage base controller results like `NotFound` or `Ok`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Automapper package 9.0.0 or superior, you will need to explicitly configure maps.

I resolve this downgrading the AutoMapper to 8.0.0 and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection to version 6.0.0